# What is causing a Symbolic pkg v2.9.0: error?

Tags: python, octave

I run Octave 5.1 on windows 10 (python 3.9 is installed). I try to run this code:

```
pkg load symbolic
syms x1 x2 x3 y1 y2 y3 x0 y0 
vars=[x1 x2 x3 y1 y2 y3];
gbasis( [x1+x1*x2-y1*y2+x1*x2*x3-y1*y2*x3-y1*x2*y3-x1*y2*y3-(1/11)*x0, y1+x1*xy2+x2*y1+y1*x2*x3+x1*y2*x3+x1*x2*y3-y1*y2*y3-(1/11)*y0, x1^2+y1^2-1, x2^2+y2^2-1, x3^2+y3^2-1],vars)
```

and always get the followin error:

```
Symbolic pkg v2.9.0: error: Cannot run the Python executable "python3"
    Try "sympref diagnose" for more information.
error: called from
    assert_have_python_and_sympy at line 61 column 7
    python_ipc_popen2 at line 79 column 5
    python_ipc_driver at line 62 column 15
    pycall_sympy__ at line 163 column 11
    valid_sym_assumptions at line 38 column 10
    assumptions at line 82 column 7
    syms at line 97 column 13
    gb at line 3 column 1
```

I tried `setenv PYTHON python3` or `setenv PYTHON python`  as some people on github recommend but it changes nothing. Has anyone solved the problem?

Comment: What did you get as an output to ‘sympref diagnose’? And from a command prompt are you able to call either python or python3?

Comment: And second, it’s worth noting that the latest version of Octave (v6.2.0) comes with the ‘bundled for windows’ symbolic package that doesn’t rely on an external python installation, in addition to all of the other improvements with the new version. Would recommend upgrading if you don’t have a particular reason to stay with the old version. Alternatively, you can use the bundled symbolic package obtained directly from the GitHub if you fail to find a solution to this current problem

Comment: @NickJ My university uses that version so i think it is safer to stick with that for the moment. I uninstalled  Octave and installed it again along with the symbolic package and its working now. Thank you!